# A question on GCT

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-complexity

In http://ramakrishnadas.cs.uchicago.edu/gctriemann.ps it is stated that there is an unknown non-standard riemann hypothesis. AFAIK riemann hypothesis in AG was shown using Etale cohomology by Artin, Deligne, Grothendieck, Serre first followed by Kedlaya following Dwork's work using padic cohomology. What is non-standard riemann hypothesis that the paper is talking about? How does it fit into GCT picture and is there a conjectured theory analogous to Weil cohomology? Note there is also a conjectured Motivic cohomology in AG from which every other cohomology theory could be derived in AG. So does motivic cohomology have anything to do with non-standard 'riemann hypothesis'?